# random distribution of time ranges minimizing overlap

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, distribution, scheduling

I have 5 job arrays of varying length/steps.

```
work = [
    np.arange(9),
    np.arange(39),
    np.arange(58),
    np.arange(24),
    np.arange(16)
]
```

And a randomized schedule:

```
now = datetime.now().replace(hour=2)
end = now.replace(hour=22, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()

schedule = np.linspace(now.timestamp(), end.timestamp(), sum(len(v) for v in work))
rng.shuffle(schedule_range)
worker_schedule = np.split(schedule, np.add.accumulate([len(v) for v in work][:-1]))
```

I believe this gets me a schedule where the job start times are distributed somewhat randomly with respect to each worker/machine but evenly on aggregate. However each job runtime varies and I would like to avoid hot-spots where I get a bunch of overlapping jobs running simultaneously. Assuming I knew the job run times ahead of time, so:

```
work = [
    np.random.uniform(5,10,9),
    np.random.uniform(5,10,39),
    np.random.uniform(5,10,58),
    np.random.uniform(5,10,24),
    np.random.uniform(5,10,16)
]
```

Where each value in the array represents the expected run time for the job step at that index and the array itself is the job. How would I go about creating a schedule that would limit simultaneously running steps to be at maximum N while spreading out the total job steps evenly over fixed period of time T? A nice bonus to have here would be to have random distribution for each step within a job over a fixed time period T but evenly distributed on aggregate over all job steps for that period.

What concepts can I google to get a good understanding of the problem and known approaches?
Finally, what would be a good way to visualize this with pyplot? (currently using histograms for the start time distribution but what would be the best way to represent the run-time range)

Edit 1:
Job Shop Scheduling problem seems to want to optimize makespan, (time as I understand it) while I would like to keep that fixed but optimize the distribution such that overlap is reduced.

Comment: I may be totally wrong but I think you are trying to solve a job scheduling problem like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling). For the plot, you could try to draw a Gantt chart.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes this is a scheduling problem. That was an interesting read and while not exactly my problem (I don't want to reduce makespan but overlap, and I want to fill out a fixed period of time instead of reduce it), it has led me to some other scheduling problems that are somewhat similar. I've adjusted my question to better explain.

Comment: Is it accurate to say that the optimal solution for this is minimal makespan with a limit on concurrent jobs?  And further that there are no prerequisites involved?  I am confused by what you started to say about workers.

Comment: @AirSquid the makespan should be fixed, we should be optimizing concurrency (less is better). I guess we can consider workers machines as these scheduling problems use that terminology. The ideal solution has even distribution across all machines while minimizing overlap for a fixed makespan T, and a bonus here would be to have each machine's schedule somewhat random.